# Label schemes by language in Spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy

From the [Spacy documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features):

> For a list of the fine-grained and coarse-grained part-of-speech tags assigned by spaCy’s models across different languages, see the label schemes documented in the models directory.

I assume this is referring to the [parts of speech tags](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#pos-tagging), eg: `VERB`, `NOUN`, `NUM` etc., and that this list will be different for each language.

Is this a correct assumption?

I followed the link in the documentation [to the models directory](https://spacy.io/models), but could not find a list of the valid POS tags for each language.

https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#pos-tagging

**Answer**

Thanks to @polm23 for the answer, here's a screen shot with the navigation, in case anyone else can't find it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the "label scheme" on the page for any individual language.

[image: label scheme screenshot]

The VERB NOUN type tags, that go in the `.pos` attribute, are from Universal Dependencies, and are mostly the same between languages. The coarse-grained tags, for the `.tag` attribute, can be anything and are unique to each language as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I must be going blind!

Comment: No worries. They could be more prominent but we collapse them to keep the page from getting unusably long.